# Backing up the iCloud Photo Library when it won't fit on my internal drive

Tags: icloud, photos

I love the iCloud Photo Library. Formerly an Aperture user, I enjoy having my entire library available on every device and now use it as my master repository. I upload raw files into it, taken from my DSLR, and of course the photos my iPhone takes. It's great. None of the devices I have, carry sufficient storage to download the entire library and so I have them all set to 'optimize'. Which is fine for day to day use, and even while editing as it downloads when needed. But I keep reading horror stories about libraries getting wiped out through bugs in Apple's software, and just generally speaking am getting increasingly worried I have just 1 copy of my entire library: the copy in iCloud.

So, I want to back up my library. But my drive is too small to make a copy of the library onto it. So, how?

"Attach an external drive" ... I tried doing this. And while I can store the library on the external drive, this then means I no longer have ANY photos on my laptop when I'm not at my desk.

"Create a second library with different sync settings" ... It's not possible to have 2 different libraries both sync down from iCloud, it turns out.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility could be to have two users on the computer, and having one of them setup with the library on the external disk and enabling "Download originals to this Mac", and having your main user with the library locally and the previously mentioned setting disabled.

That way you would only sync your photos to the external drive when logged in to the second user.
Take a couple clicks to do the "backup", but it would work.

Comment: Ooh I like that solution! Thanks for the suggestion. Might try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set your library to be on the external drive, turn on the setting to keep originals locally, then download everything.

Then take a copy of that library on the external drive, turn off the setting to download originals locally, and move the library back to the internal drive?

I can't see why that would not work ...

Comment: I agree, that would work. But that is one hell of a process to go through every time I want to make a backup! I was hoping for something that 'just works'.

Comment: It answers the question as asked - if you want to do regular ongoing backups , I don't see how that can be possible without using an additional device, say a new computer with more storage? ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to make sure that your Mac has download originals selected (if it can bear the space) and then once all of the iCloud Photos have been downloaded to the Mac, you can go to File -> Export All and then make a folder on your external hard drive and then you will be able to save the photos to your external drive directly.

If you need step by step directions let me know.

Comment: The internal drive isn’t big enough to accommodate the entire download. That’s why I’m struggling.

Comment: How big is the internal drive? How big is the external drive? How big are your iCloud Photo size?

Comment: The internal drive doesn’t have enough space to accommodate the library. The external does. Please read the post.

Comment: I read the post. It lacks the actual sizes needed to determine a possible solution. I'm looking for size amounts.

Comment: The iPhoto library is about 80GB in size. My internal drive is 256 and does not have 80GB available. My external drive does.

Comment: And the size of the external drive?

Comment: It’s a 4TB drive with ample space.

Comment: Then you can copy your photo library file, place it on your external, then open that library and then you can go to File -> Export All and then make a folder on your external hard drive and then you will be able to save the photos to your external drive directly. But this wont get you all 80GB. Simply because iCloud only operates on the internal drive.

Comment: Thanks, but that is actually not true. The local library file that syncs with iCloud Photo Library (called the 'System Photo Library') can be on any drive, internal or external. The problem with this approach is that it leaves me with zero photos on my laptop, as outlined in the original post.

Comment: True you can move the system file but if you want your entire iCloud photo library then if you try moving the system library and then go to preferences in photos, you'll see that it says the hard drive doesn't have enough storage. iCloud photo library works on the internal startup disk not an external.

Comment: It does on my machine.